# Connecting a table in mySQl- Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I am trying to connect two tables on mySQL, one has an ID associated to a specific person, and another has a message that has been sent to the person on the website. In order to associate a specific message with a specific person it has been sent to, I am trying to have an inner join. However, I get a Warning:

> #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value.

Can someone please advise?

My inner join is as follows:

```
SELECT gymafi_admin.id, gymafi_admin_tominbox.message 
FROM gymafi_admin 
INNER JOIN gymafi_admin_tominbox ON gymafi_admin.id = gymafi_admin_tominbox.message
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results.

Comment: What is the schema for both tables?

Answer (score 0):

This join condition does not look right:

```
ON gymafi_admin.id = gymafi_admin_tominbox.message
```

Presumably, the column on the left is a number (that represents the id of the user), while on the right side we have a string (the message). This would explain the warning that you are getting, since MySQL would then attempt to convert the string (`message`) to an integer value in order to compare them.

I do suspect that the column on the right side should be something else, that stores the `id` of the user. Assuming that this column is called `admin_id`, your query would look like:

```
SELECT a.id, i.message 
FROM gymafi_admin a
INNER JOIN gymafi_admin_tominbox i ON a.id = i.admin_id
```

Note that I added table aliases to shorten it and make it more readable.